# Difference between apply node and op node in theano

Tags: theano

Theano beginner here. I was just going through the graph structures section on deeplearning.net and I have a doubt.

It is stated that in the tutorial that, "Apply node represents the application of an op to some variables. It is important to draw the difference between the definition of a computation represented by an op and its application to some actual data which is represented by the apply node."

In theano, the application of a computation to data is performed by first creating a function and plugging the appropriate value in f(). Where does the op node come into the picture ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP in theano means the computation, like add, dot, convolution. And we define all our works by OPs and then build it to a specific graph by `theano.function()`. Look at [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/extending/graphstructures.html).

> Theano represents symbolic mathematical computations as graphs. These
>   graphs are composed of interconnected Apply, Variable and Op nodes.
>   Apply node represents the application of an op to some variables.

[image: op and apply]

I am not sure this answers your questions. Let's me know if it's still unclear.